# How to fix ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, parameterized-query

I am trying to parameterize my query in order to be able to add in title with ' in the full world , for example "Can't log in". I did some reading and realised i have to paramterize my query. So far my query before was as follows :

```
def create_issue(self, title, description):
        cursor = self._conn.cursor()
        try:
            cursor.execute(
                """INSERT INTO issues(
                    title,
                    description
                ) VALUES('{}', '{}')""".format(title, description))
            cursor.execute("select last_insert_rowid()")
            return cursor.fetchone()[0]
        finally:
            cursor.close()
```

I have tried to paramterize this query in order for it to accept ' as part of the string and not throw up a OperationalError. I have tried the following below:

```
def create_issue(self, title, description):
        cursor = self._conn.cursor()
        try:


            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO issues (title, description) VALUES (?,?)", {title, description})
            cursor.execute("select last_insert_rowid()")
            return cursor.fetchone()[0]
        finally:
            cursor.close()
```

I get the following error :

> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO issues (title, description) VALUES
>   (?,?)", {title, description}) ValueError: parameters are of
>   unsupported type

What is it that i am doing wrong and how can i get my query to work

```
My table properties are as follows:
CREATE TABLE issues(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(255),
  description VARCHAR(255),
  opened_datetime CHAR(26) DEFAULT (datetime('now')),
  closed_datetime CHAR(26) DEFAULT (datetime('now'))
)
```

I am passing in the text box title the following input "Can't log in "
In the description i am passing in the following input " User dev cannot log in "

Comment: what are your table properties for column title, description. Also can you please post what are you passing as title and description?

Comment: I have just updated my question with table properties and what i am passing in for title and description @be_good_do_good

Comment: Can you include an example showing what's passed in, how? An [mcve] is important for answering.

Comment: @airlogic: *"ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type"*: Your parameters are of type `set = {..., ....}`. You have to use of type `sequence = (..., ...)`